# syntax error in join operation access

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(table1 FULL OUTER JOIN [FY14 PLEDGE_TOTAL]
ON table1.[Id] = [FY14 PLEDGE_TOTAL].[SID]);
```

I don't know why I'm getting this error on Access. When I remove the parentheses after 'FROM', I get syntax error on From clause. Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access does not support OUTER JOIN. You need the variant which would be LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN with an Is Null criteria on the field where the data do not exist.

Here is Microsoft's take on the issue : http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/creating-an-outer-join-query-in-access-HA001034555.aspx

Or something much helpful : http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3516561/Implementing-the-Equivalent-of-a-FULL-OUTER-JOIN-in-Microsoft-Access.htm

Comment: Actually 'LEFT OUTER JOIN' was what I was looking for, which was mentioned in the article you shared. Though I had no idea that Access didn't accept 'OUTER JOIN'. Had been struggling for quite a while. Thanks a ton!

Comment: You are most welcome. Please feel free to mark this as answer, if it has solved your problem. Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

MS Access don't have support for `FULL OUTER JOIN` but the same can be emulated using `UNION` of both a `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN` like below

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN [FY14 PLEDGE_TOTAL] fpt 
ON t1.[Id] = fpt.[SID]

UNION

SELECT *
FROM table1 t2 
RIGHT JOIN [FY14 PLEDGE_TOTAL] fpt1 
ON t2.[Id] = fpt1.[SID];
```